# Using lenses to update RandomGen inside state struct in Haskell

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I'm using a `StdGen` inside a larger state struct and want to implement the `RandomGen` class on the state struct. Using lenses I came up with the following implementation:

```
module Test
    ( StateData(..)
    , randomGen
    ) where

import Lens.Micro.Platform
import System.Random

data StateData = StateData
    { _randomGen :: StdGen
    } deriving (Show)

randomGen :: Lens' StateData StdGen
randomGen = lens _randomGen (\ s x -> s { _randomGen = x })

instance RandomGen StateData where
    next s = r & _2 .~ (s & randomGen .~ (r ^. _2))
        where r = (s ^. randomGen ^. to next)
    split s = r & _1 .~ (s & randomGen .~ (r ^. _1))
                & _2 .~ (s & randomGen .~ (r ^. _2))
        where r = (s ^. randomGen ^. to split)
```

To simplify this definition (and future definitions like it) I would like to generalise the pattern as follows:

```
reinsert :: (a -> b) -> Lens' s a -> [Lens b b' a s] -> a -> b'
reinsert f a bs s
     = foldr (&) r [b .~ (s & a .~ (r ^. b)) | b <- bs]
     where r = (s ^. a ^. to f)

instance RandomGen StateData where
    next = reinsert next randomGen [_2]
    split = reinsert split randomGen [_1, _2]
```

There is a problem with this approach though. The type declaration of `reinsert` is an "Illegal polymorphic type". I understand this as the type being to complex for Haskell to deal with. If I remove the type declaration the first use of the `a` lens turns it into a class `Getting`, making the second use as `ASetter` illegal; the same happens to `b` inside the list comprehension.

Is there a way to fix this? Or alternatively, is there a better way to implement the `RandomGen` instance on `StateData`?

Cheers, Johan

Edit: a bit simpler, but not solving the core issue:

```
instance RandomGen StateData where
    next s  = (s ^. randomGen ^. to next) 
            & _2 %~ (\ x -> s & randomGen .~ x)
    split s = (s ^. randomGen ^. to split)
            & _1 %~ (\ x -> s & randomGen .~ x)
            & _2 %~ (\ x -> s & randomGen .~ x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, avoid taking `Lens` / `Getter` / `Setter` etc.. as arguments to functions, take `ALens` / `Getting` / `ASetter` instead. These are basically the “specialised to one use scenario” versions, which doesn't require pesky Rank-N polymorphism etc.. Rank-N by itself is merely tricky for the type checker, but if you also have these types *in a list*, it breaks down completely (this would be impredicative polymorphism, which GHC has never supported properly).

So in this case, it is `ALens`. The only slight problem is, `.~` actually wants `ASetter`, which is a strictly more special, but (in Haskell) distinct type. Likewise for `^.`. There are two solutions:

- [“Clone” the lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.17/docs/Control-Lens-Lens.html#v:cloneLens), to get in the function a polymorphic version again.
- Use the “lensy” getter and setter operators, i.e. [`#~`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.17/docs/Control-Lens-Lens.html#v:-35--126-) for `.~`.

Comment: Thanks, that explains a lot. The problem is a bit harder still: in my example `_1` and `_2` will have different types, so the fold is never going to work the way it is written now. Each iteration of the fold would have a different type of tuple. I'll accept your answer anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

One possible problem with your definition of `reinsert` is that it ties the structure of the final result to the structure of the transformed field.

How about this alternative definition of `reinsert`?

```
-- Pry apart a field from a value,
-- returning a pair of the value and a function to reconstruct the original value.
pry :: Lens' r x -> Iso' r (x -> r,x)
pry l = iso (\r -> (\x -> set l x r, view l r)) (uncurry ($))

-- Given
-- a lens into a field
-- a transformation of the field
-- a function that takes a reconstructor and the transformed field, and returns other thing
-- a starting value
-- return the other thing
reinsert :: Lens' a b -> (b -> b') -> ((b -> a) -> b' -> c) -> a -> c
reinsert l transform packer = 
    view $ pry l . alongside id (to transform) . to (uncurry packer)
```

It uses the [`alongside`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.17/docs/Control-Lens-Lens.html#v:alongside) combinator. (The `pry` isn't strictly needed, you could simply `view` and `set` in `reinsert`.)

With it, we could define the `RandomGen` instance like this:

```
instance RandomGen StateData where
    next  = reinsert randomGen next fmap
    split = reinsert randomGen split (\f (s1,s2) -> (f s1, f s2))
```